# Make featured image required + show custom error message

Tags: wordpress, hook, custom-post-type

I have tried to combine my two functions but i can't figure out how. I would like to make the **featured image required**. I know that there are lots of similar questions but they always end in `wp_die();` that's not really user friendly in my opinion. I can't figure the Wordpress error message thing out.

**What my code should do:**

1. Check does the post have an featured image on save / publish
2. If not, make the post a draft and show an error message (Featured Image is required! The post was not published / updated.)

PS: Currently the error message gets shown immediately when the post is opened or created. It should not be like that.

My current code is:

```
function featured_image_required($post_id, $post, $update){
    $post_type  = $post->post_type;
    $id         = $post_id;

    if(!has_post_thumbnail($id) AND $post_type == "custom_post_type") {
        remove_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required'); 
        $query = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
        );
        wp_update_post($query, true);
        add_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required', 10, 3 );

function show_editor_message($messages){
    global $post;
    $post_type = $post->post_type;

    if (!has_post_thumbnail($post_id) AND $post_type == "custom_post_type") {
        $error_message = 'Featured Image is required! The post was not published.';
        add_settings_error('featured_image_required', '', $error_message, 'error');
        settings_errors( 'featured_image_required' );
        return;
    }
    return $messages;
}
add_action('post_updated_messages', 'show_editor_message');
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is just to test against the initial status of the post (here 'auto-draft') and not to display the message, if the post is in that state.

The `save_post` action requires an additional check against the status, otherwise the post will always be put back to the draft state, if it does not have a Featured Image (not possible to trash the post, for example).

Here's the modified code:

```
function featured_image_required($post_id, $post, $update){
    $post_type  = $post->post_type;
    $id         = $post_id;

    if($post->post_status == "publish" AND !has_post_thumbnail($id) AND $post_type == "custom_post_type") {
        remove_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required'); 
        $query = array(
            'ID' => $id,
            'post_status' => 'draft',
        );
        wp_update_post($query, true);
        add_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required');
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'featured_image_required', 10, 3 );

function show_editor_message($messages){
    global $post;
    $post_type = $post->post_type;

    if ($post->post_status != "auto-draft" AND !has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) AND $post_type == "custom_post_type") {
        $error_message = 'Featured Image is required! The post was not published.';
        add_settings_error('featured_image_required', '', $error_message, 'error');
        settings_errors( 'featured_image_required' );
        return;
    }
    return $messages;
}
add_action('post_updated_messages', 'show_editor_message');
```